# How to properly adjust resolution setting

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, resolution

I am making a poster for a billboard contest and the resolution for the billboard on the website is 400x1400 pixels (I have included a screenshot). For blender to I set the x and y resolution to 400 and 1400? I didn't know if I needed to make any conversions?
[image: re]

Answer (score 3):

In the *Properties > Output Properties* panel, you can simply set the `X` and `Y` values to `1400` and `400`. As long as the `%` slider below is at %100, you'll get exactly a 1400x400px image as a result. You can use this slider to resize your output image without changing the ratio. If you set that to 50%, for example, you'd get a 700x200px image. It's soft-limited to %100, but if you want you can click in the box and enter higher values (%200 for a 2800x800px image, say).

If you have a Camera present in the scene, you'll notice that the outline of its frame will match the ratio of your output resolution:

[image]

Comment: if I double the resolution to 800x2800 will that give me a higher quality render while keeping the same size?

Comment: @user142885 Really depends on what you mean by "quality". If you render it at %200 so it's 2800x800, it'll be twice as big, so it won't be the same size, but it'll be the same ratio. Some images *might* get nicer if you render them bigger then resize them down to the desired dimensions, but not usually. Why don't you just try it with some simple scenes?