# How do I change render resolution in Blende 3.0

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, resolution

So I'm relatively new to blender. Are samples the same as resolution and if so how do they work? I don't know what resolution I'm rendering at right now but I want it to be higher. How do I do this because I don't see a resolution option?

Comment: does this answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254726/how-to-properly-adjust-resolution-setting

Comment: @Harry McKenzie sort of. I think it should let me make the image bigger and essentially double the quality. Like its les pixely if i zoom in

Comment: in the Output panel > Format > increase the Resolution?

Answer (score 0):

More samples means a higher quality image with less noise, as well as more realistic caustics, reflections, and volumes. Increasing the resolution increases the pixel size and dimensions of the final render.